# WPF Listbox multiple selection with CheckBox in template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a listbox with a datatemplate that contains a checkbox and textblock. How do I get the multiselection working with the checkbox in the template so that selection is based on the isChecked property of the checkbox? The need I have is to have a dropdown with checkboxes that could cater for multiselection. This is what I have sofar. Please feel free to give suggestions on where I could better this code as this is the whole point.

[image]

XAML:

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkCentreItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding WorkCentre}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" -  "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

     <telerik:RadListBox 
        SelectionMode="Multiple" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Grid.RowSpan="1" 
        Margin="-1,20,0,3"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SampleWorkCentres}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WorkCentreItem}" 
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
        SelectionChanged="RadListBox_SelectionChanged">         
    </telerik:RadListBox>
```

Model:

```
    #region SampleWorkCentres
    public const string SampleWorkCentresPropertyName = "SampleWorkCentres";
    private ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre> _sampleWorkCentres;
    public ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre> SampleWorkCentres
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._sampleWorkCentres == null)
            {
                using (SysproKitIssueEntities db = new SysproKitIssueEntities())
                {
                    this._sampleWorkCentres = new ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre>(db.BomWorkCentres.Select(x => x).Distinct().ToList());
                }
            }
            return this._sampleWorkCentres;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._sampleWorkCentres == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            this._sampleWorkCentres = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(SampleWorkCentresPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region SelectedWorkCentres
    public const string SelectedWorkCentresPropertyName = "SelectedWorkCentres";
    private ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre> _selectedWorkCentres = new ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre>();
    public ObservableCollection<BomWorkCentre> SelectedWorkCentres
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedWorkCentres;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._selectedWorkCentres != value)
            {
                this._selectedWorkCentres = value;
            }
            this._sampleGridItems = null;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(SampleGridItemsPropertyName);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedWorkCentresPropertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: can you not use radGridView and have a selection column instead ?

Comment: that was my first thought but I do not have that much space available on the ui for it and the selection column clutters the interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should data bind the `Checkbox.IsChecked` to the [`ListBoxItem.IsSelected` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected(v=vs.110).aspx) using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding WorkCentre}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
```

Comment: the binding IsSelected, must that be property of item type the listbox displays? getting object reference not set to an instance of object

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're supposed to be data binding one control property to another... you're not declaring any properties here.